# PAD_INDEX and FILLFACTOR on clustered Identity index

Tags: sql-server, index

I am trying to work out what setting for PAD_INDEX I should use for a `clustered index` on a `IDENTITY` column, the table is rarely going to be updated after first insert so I am looking for the setting that will result in the most of the space in the pages being used.

However I have found some documentation on the MSDN that seems to conflict with each other (or at least confuse me enough to ask for clarification).

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

> PAD_INDEX = { ON | OFF } When ON, the percentage of free space
>   specified by FILLFACTOR is applied to the intermediate level pages of
>   the index. When OFF or a FILLFACTOR value is not specified, the
>   intermediate level pages are filled to near capacity leaving enough
>   space for at least one row of the maximum size the index can have,
>   considering the set of keys on the intermediate pages. The default is
>   OFF.

And from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177459.aspx

> The fill-factor value is a percentage from 1 to 100, and the server-wide default is 0 which means that the leaf-level pages are filled to capacity.

Given the clause `When a FILLFACTOR value is not specified`, does that mean that the default FILLFACTOR of 0 is ignored regardless of the setting of `PAD_INDEX`?

Following on from that does that mean that I need to specify both `PAD_INDEX = ON` and `FILLFACTOR = 100` on my identity clustered index to get maximum page usage?

Comment: The first one applies to _intermediate level_ index pages only, while the second one is about _leaf pages_.  I can't test it, but from these I'd say that if you set `FILLFACTOR` to 100, your pages (at all levels) will be filled to capacity, regardless of the setting of `PAD_INDEX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PAD_INDEX` only applies to non leave level pages. By default those are filled full.

So specifying `PAD_INDEX=ON` together with `FILLFACTOR` is only useful when you specify a fillfactor smaller then 100%.

In your case, specifying `PAD_INDEX` is not necessary, since by default your leave pages are how you want them. Full.